# Should a module file look like this?

Tags: views, 6

I've been having problems with one of my Drupal sites and have narrowed the problem down to the Views module. In my Apache error log, I see this:

> [Tue Oct 18 09:57:08 2011] [warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ']' in /home/lakedistrict-holidayideas/public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/views/handlers/views_handler_filter_in_operator.inc on line 206

Looking at the views_handler_filter_in_operator.inc file, I see this on line 206:

```
 $form['value']['#dep
```

Does that appear to be a normal line of code? To my untrained eyes, it looks incomplete.

I've reinstalled the module, but the problem remains.

If it appears to be that there's a problem with the module, I'll make a post on the Views issue queue on Drupal.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Views module version 2.12, I looked up that file in the repository viewer:
http://drupalcode.org/project/views.git/blob/42fe4029ca7d7410f15933032a17e979bb0957c4:/handlers/views_handler_filter_in_operator.inc

Looks like line 206 should be:

```
$form['value']['#dependency'] = array($source => $this->operator_values(1));
```

I'd try re-downloading the entire Views module. Maybe your copy got corrupted along the way.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using 6.x-2.12. I understand that this is the latest release (aside from the alpha).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, Chris - I've only just noticed the edit to your original post.

Thanks for the reply - I'll take another shot at reinstalling it.